# Using string.Join instead of foreach

Tags: c#, string, linq, join

I'm trying to refactor my code to make it smaller and better looking. I'm trying to override the `ToString` method that returns class name and all fields it has with their current states. Here is my code:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    var properties = GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).OrderBy(x => x.Name);
    //StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    //result.Append(GetType().Name);
    //result.Append("(");
    //foreach (var e in GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).OrderBy(x => x.Name))
    //{
    //    result.Append(e.Name);
    //    result.Append(": ");
    //    result.Append(e.GetValue(this));
    //    result.Append(";");
    //    result.Append(" ");
    //}

    //result.Remove(result.Length - 2, 2);
    //result.Append(")");
    //return result.ToString();
}
```

I got an advice that I could use `string.Join` combined with some LINQ and that would do the job, but I cant figure out how to do that. Thanks in advice!

Comment: I think this code is a really terrible way to override `ToString` anyway. It looks like you're trying to find a generic method, but there really isn't one. Every class should be handled in it's own way.

Comment: You can cram everything on one line as the answer below does, but that doesn't make your code any more readable. Removing the StringBuilder also makes it less efficient. Why the focus on "small" and "good looking"? The best code is fast and readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be something like:
(Edited: cached the property infos instead of recalculating on every ToString() call)

```
static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> propertyInfos;
static MyClass()
{
    propertyInfos = typeof(MyClass).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance).OrderBy(x => x.Name);
}

public override string ToString()
{
    return $"{GetType().Name}({string.Join("; ", propertyInfos.Select(x => $"{x.Name}: {x.GetValue(this)}"))})";
}
```

However, I don't think using such reflection for the ToString() implementation is recommended, since it's not very efficient, and  ToString() implementations should be quick.

Comment: Correct, except for the property values.

Comment: You probably want to use `"; "` as the separator instead of `";"` based on the OP's code.

Comment: Instead of overriding `ToString`, how about we create a function with an `Enumerable` return type? That might perform better depending on where it's used.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Most reflection calls are cached internally.

Comment: @Metheny its working, but can I somehow attach class name at the beggining of the string and a closing brace at the end? For example original output was "PersonName(FirstName: A; LastName: B)" and the output with ur code is "FirstName: A; LastName: B"?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`ObjectDumper`](https://github.com/thomasgalliker/ObjectDumper) to do the hard work of stringifying the properties of the class.

Usage example:

```
class Demo
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return ObjectDumper.Dump(this, DumpStyle.Console);
    }
}

var demo = new Demo() { Key = 1, Name = "Foo" };
Console.WriteLine(demo.ToString());
```

Output:

```
{Demo}
  Key: 1
  Name: "Foo"
```

If the output is not what you want, you could steal `ObjectDumper`'s [source code](https://github.com/thomasgalliker/ObjectDumper/blob/master/ObjectDumper/Internal/ObjectDumperConsole.cs), and modify it to your needs.